# NodeJS: How to use Connection Pooling with MySQL correctly? How useful it is?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database-connection, connection-pooling

I'm using connection pooling in NodeJS with MySQL. There are several connections remain in processlist in **Sleep** state, which results too many connection in the end even if site does not have heavy traffic.

Here is sample code as I'm using it:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    database: '****'
});
pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
    connection.query("SELECT * from test", function (error, data) {
        connection.release();
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            // perform further process
        }
    });
});
```

Is connection not released at proper location? Suggest if there could be any improvement in code above.

Comment: Still not found any solution!!!

Answer (score 0):

That is what pool does, you can add connection limit...

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    user: '***',
    password: '***',
    database: '****'
});
```

Comment: Set connectionLimit: 2, still can see connections more than 2.

Comment: What if Node creating a separate pool with every new http request?

Comment: Is there any way to prevent this? Any sample code you can refer to

Comment: you have to create a pool on application start and keep it in a global variable to use later... that will be the correct approach.